# React Virtualized - Screen going blank after scrolling a long list of itsm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm working on a long list of items. For that I'm using react-virtualized (https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized). But I'm facing the below issue.

[image]

When I try scrolling to the bottom for 2 seconds, it's blank then data is loading. It's not very smooth. This https://2v9j5.csb.app/ is the CodeSandBox link.

Comment: It would be helpful if you had kept the codesanbox link up, I am having a similar issue and want to see what you had vs. what the answerer showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I inspected in this use case we shouldn't remount the root div for the `rowRenderer` :  `<div key={key} style={style}>` on scrolling as used on the [docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md#rowrenderer), so this should fix the performance problem :

```
function rowRenderer({ key, index, isScrolling, style }) {
  const content = isScrolling ? (
    <div>Scrolling...</div>
  ) : (
    <ListItem idx={index} item={airports[index]} />
  );
  return (
    <div key={key} style={style}>
      {content}
    </div>
  );
}
```